# Unable to modify Ember mirage fixture from within acceptance test

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixtures, ember-testing, ember-cli-mirage

I have a fixture create which looks somewhat like this.

```
// mirage/fixtures/people.js
 export default {
      'people': [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Ram',
         },
         {
          'id': 2,
          'name': 'Raja',
         }
       ]
    }
```

Inside my acceptance test I'm using this array. But within my test, I want to modify this people array and add, suppose another object

```
{
   'id': 3,
   'name': 'John',
}
```

Note: I dont want to use factories as I dont want all datas to be dynamically generated, so I want to take this array from fixtures, push my new object into this array and then return it. What is the correct way to do it?

Note2: Don't suggest adding this object in fixtures itself, because I want to dynamically add items to the fixture based on conditions in my test.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Which Mirage version are you using? AFAIK `server.create` is used only with factories. In order to load fixture data you should run [`server.loadFixtures()`](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/configuration/#loadFixtures)

Comment: Hi @RamyBenAroya, in my config.js for mirage, I'm doing 

`import peopleFromFixture  from '/mirage/fixtures/people';`
`this.get('/people', (schema, request) => {`
`    return peopleFromFixture;`
` });`

Comment: This sounds wrong. You never create the models in the mirage db. You basically created your own small db for people which is the exported object in `/mirage/fixtures/people`.

Comment: @RamyBenAroya sorry Indeed I was not using server.create for fixture. My bad, i've edited the question now but my original question still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty straight forward. In the mirage config, we **shouldn't** be doing this

```
// import peopleFromFixture from '/mirage/fixtures/people'; 
// this.get('/people', (schema, request) => {  
// return peopleFromFixture;  });
```

instead read data from factories and populate original fixture values with `server.loadFixtures('people')`.

So config.js will look like =>

```
this.get('/people');
```

Set your factory like this =>

```
import { Factory } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default Factory.extend({
  id(i) {  return i+1; },
  name() { return faker.name.findName(); }
});
```

Inside your test case, populate original and new values like this =>

```
server.loadFixtures('people');
server.create('people', { name: 'John' });
```